# HOW CAN I CONCATENATE :NEW OR :OLD WITH A VARIABLE?

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace TRIGGER TEST_TRIGG
BEFORE UPDATE ON ALUMNES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
updatedcols varchar2(3000);
begin
for r in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name ='ALUMNES')
    loop
       IF UPDATING(r.column_name) THEN
       updatedcols := updatedcols || ',' || r.column_name;
        INSERT INTO control_de_dades_alumnes (TIPUS_OPERACIO, USUARI, DIA, COLUMNA, DADA_ANTIGA) VALUES ('UPDATE', USER, SYSDATE, updatedcols, :OLD.updatedcols);
       END IF;
    end loop;
end;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOJp.png)

How can I concatenate :NEW or :OLD with a variable # Oracle #Script #Concatenate.

With a Select I collect the name of the column that I am updating and I store it in a Variable called updatedcols so that I want to concatenate the variable with :OLD to collect the old data of that field but it does not let me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically access attributes of the `:new` or `:old` pseudo-records.  You'd need to have a series of static `if` statements

```
IF updating( 'COLUMN1' )
THEN
  updatedCols := updatedCols || ', ' || :new.column1;
END IF; 
IF updating( 'COLUMN2' )
THEN
  updatedCols := updatedCols || ', ' || :new.column2;
END IF;
```

Of course, you could write some code that would use the data dictionary tables like `user_tab_columns` to generate the trigger code with all the static column references.  That's generally a lot more effort than just writing the trigger statically but it may be worth it if you're trying to create similar triggers on a large number of tables.  You'd also need to ensure that your development process included regenerating the trigger every time someone added or removed a column from the table.

As an aside, note that `updating( 'COLUMN1' )` returns true if the triggering `update` statement includes `column1` whether or not the value in `column1` actually changes.  If you are trying to capture changes, that is rarely what you really want.  You generally want to compare `:new.column1` to `:old.column1` to see if there was actually a change in value.

And as a generally architectural approach, having a single log table where you store changes from a bunch of different tables rarely works out well in my experience.  If the system gets popular, the log table gets so large it becomes almost impossible to query effectively.  It becomes very hard to answer questions like "What was the value of `column1` in the row where `id` = 12345 on Jan 15, 2022 at 4:15 pm"  In your case, that is effectively impossible because nothing in your log table tells you which row's data changed.